# Unable to create table using html

Tags: html, xml, html-table

Basically, I am making a XML stylesheet. So I am using the below method:

e.g. Now it will create, the headers but what about the name and phone under a header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to express this table layout in XHTML semantic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201168/how-to-express-this-table-layout-in-xhtml-semantic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td  style="text-align: center" rowspan="3" valign="top">
            Name</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            Retailer Contact</td>
        <td  style="text-align: center" rowspan="3" valign="top">
            Request Date</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            Request</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            Name</td>
        <td >
            Phone</td>
        <td >
            Title</td>
        <td >
            Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td >
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td >
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```